# Why recyclerview doesn't show any data on first tap?

Tags: android

Recyclerview doesn't show any data on first click but whenever i come back from this recyclerview it works well

i used this adapter methods

```
recyclerview.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

Comment: add some more detail.

Comment: Insufficient information, please share some more details

Answer (score 0):

I can’t guess what is your exact problem.

Then did you call

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
```

after data is receievrd?

Comment: I am adding items to my recycler list from an ADD activity which opens by clicking a button in the recyclerview activity. but when I add and close the ADD activity, the item does not show in the recyclerview activity unless I close it and open it again.

I get an ID if the add network call is successful. I then add ID to sqlite,finish the ADD activity and return to my recyclerview activity.I get the ID from sqlite and pass it to network call function to get my item.